# Does "Value Restriction" practically mean that there is no higher order functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, type-inference, higher-order-functions, mutability

Does "Value Restriction" practically mean that there is no higher order functional programming?

I have a problem that each time I try to do a bit of HOP I get caught by a VR error. Example:

```
let simple (s:string)= fun rq->1 
let oops= simple ""

type 'a SimpleType= F of (int ->'a-> 'a)
let get a = F(fun req -> id)  
let oops2= get ""
```

and I would like to know whether it is a problem of a prticular implementation of VR or it is a general problem that has no solution in a mutable type-infered language that doesn't include mutation in the type system.

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing that as a question that makes sense?

Comment: I'm not a functional-programming expert, but isn't this restriction a feature of ML-like languages that isn't shared by other functional languages (e.g. Haskell)?  If so, you might want to tag your question accordingly.

Comment: my question is: Does mutability mean a Strict VR in type a inferred functional languages.

Answer (score 6):

> Does “Value Restriction” mean that there is no higher order functional programming?

**Absolutely not!**  The value restriction barely interferes with higher-order functional programming at all.  What it *does* do is restrict some applications of *polymorphic* functions—**not** higher-order functions—at top level.

---

Let's look at your example.
Your problem is that `oops` and `oops2` are both the identity function and have type `forall 'a . 'a -> 'a`.  In other words each is a polymorphic value.  But the right-hand side is not a so-called "syntactic value"; it is a function application.  (A function application is not allowed to return a polymorphic value because if it were, you could construct a hacky function using mutable references and lists that would subvert the type system; that is, you could write a terminating function type type `forall 'a 'b . 'a -> 'b`.

Luckily in almost all practical cases, the polymorphic value in question is a function, and you can define it by eta-expanding:

```
let oops x = simple "" x
```

This idiom looks like it has some run-time cost, but depending on the inliner and optimizer, that can be got rid of by the compiler—it's just the poor typechecker that is having trouble.

The `oops2` example is more troublesome because you have to pack and unpack the value constructor:

```
let oops2 = F(fun x -> let F f = get "" in f x)
```

This is quite a but more tedious, but the anonymous function `fun x -> ...` is a syntactic value, and `F` is a datatype constructor, and a constructor applied to a syntactic value is also a syntactic value, and Bob's your uncle.  The packing and unpacking of `F` is all going to be compiled into the identity function, so `oops2` is going to compile into *exactly* the same machine code as `oops`.

Things are even nastier when you want a run-time computation to return a polymorphic value like `None` or `[]`.  As hinted at by Nathan Sanders, you can run afoul of the value restriction with an expression as simple as `rev []`:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.67 [built: Sun Oct 19 17:18:14 2008]
- val l = rev [];
stdIn:1.5-1.15 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
val l = [] : ?.X1 list
-
```

Nothing higher-order there!  And yet the value restriction applies.

In practice **the value restriction presents no barrier to the definition and use of higher-order functions**; you just eta-expand.

Comment: Although what you said about VR is true in general, you didn't answer OP's question. First, eta-expanding oops2 isn't going to work if you read the other answer or tried the program yourself. Second, I think OP already understood the reason behind this restriction, and he wanted to know if there's any better solution.

Comment: @Wei that's because I totally didn't understand OP's question (and still don't).  But I have tried to clarify.

Comment: `get` is a unary function, so you cannot write `let oops2 x = get "" x`.

Comment: @Wei: Thanks for catching my error. I've fixed the `oops2` example and tested it now.

Comment: "In practice the value restriction presents no barrier to the definition and use of higher-order functions; you just eta-expand"

I am sorry but the use of "just" in the end of this sentence here is premature. Each time I want to do something that makes sense in types I have to find a hack that breaks any fluency in my api. I am sorry but i can not ask users of my api: Please do eta reduction and unpack pack your values.
Can someone else see that this is non sense?

Comment: you start explaining FP by "Function is a normal value that you can receive as an argument and return from another function" But hey, you do eta-reduction if you want to return a polymorphic function as a value. And worse it is inside a data structure.
If you can't think of an example where it would make sense this doesn't mean that in practice it is OK.

Comment: and I added the data structure not because i like to complicate things, take for instance 

type 'a Interesting = ('a->'a)*int Option
let setI_andDoNothing i= Some (id,i)
ans somewhere in the user's code
let x= setI_andDoNothing 1

Comment: especially when i am not planning to expose data constructures outside modules.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know the details of the value restriction, so I searched and found [this article](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/valrestr.html). Here is the relevant part:

> Obviously, we aren't going to write the expression rev [] in a program, so it doesn't particularly matter that it isn't polymorphic. But what if we create a function using a function call? With curried functions, we do this all the time:
>
> ```
> - val revlists = map rev;
> ```
>
> Here revlists should be polymorphic, but the value restriction messes us up:
>
> ```
> - val revlists = map rev;
> stdIn:32.1-32.23 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
>    value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
> val revlists = fn : ?.X1 list list -> ?.X1 list list
> ```
>
> Fortunately, there is a simple trick that we can use to make revlists polymorphic. We can replace the definition of revlists with
>
> ```
> - val revlists = (fn xs => map rev xs);
> val revlists = fn : 'a list list -> 'a list list
> ```
>
> and now everything works just fine, since (fn xs => map rev xs) is a syntactic value. 
>   (Equivalently, we could have used the more common fun syntax:
>
> ```
> - fun revlists xs = map rev xs;
> val revlists = fn : 'a list list -> 'a list list
> ```
>
> with the same result.) In the literature, the trick of replacing a function-valued expression e with (fn x => e x) is known as eta expansion. It has been found empirically that eta expansion usually suffices for dealing with the value restriction.

To summarise, it doesn't look like higher-order programming is restricted so much as point-free programming. This might explain some of the trouble I have when translating Haskell code to F#.

---

Edit: Specifically, here's how to fix your first example:

```
let simple (s:string)= fun rq->1 
let oops= (fun x -> simple "" x)     (* eta-expand oops *)

type 'a SimpleType= F of (int ->'a-> 'a)
let get a = F(fun req -> id)
let oops2= get ""
```

I haven't figured out the second one yet because the type constructor is getting in the way.

Comment: but my second example is not point free, just simple function in a type. And I can NOT do eta reduction (and I find it ugly anyway) :s

Comment: `(fun req -> id)` is missing some arguments: `(fun req x -> id x)` is the eta-expanded version. Both funs are still higher order functions though. (But the second doesn't solve the value restriction, at least in OCaml.)

Comment: yes, it doesn't solve the VR. So it is not about point free but rather about functions that return functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the answer to this question](http://blogs.msdn.com/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) in the context of F#.
To summarize, in F# passing a type argument to a generic (=polymorphic) function is a run-time operation, so it is actually type-safe to generalize (as in, you will not crash at runtime). The behaviour of thusly generalized value can be surprising though.

For this particular example in F#, one can recover generalization with a type annotation and an explicit type parameter:

```
type 'a SimpleType= F of (int ->'a-> 'a)
let get a = F(fun req -> id)  
let oops2<'T> : 'T SimpleType = get ""
```